# VS 2015 + Web compiler - Show original .scss file name in chrome deleloper mode like Koala

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, web-compiler

I am using **sass** (.scss) in Visual Studio 2015 with Web compiler.

It is working great as expected.

But the only problem is I am not able to see the file name in developer mode as it shows in **Koala**

To dubug, I feel this option will be really helpful

Can anybody suggest how can I enable the same in VS 2015 please?

Answer (score 0):

I asume that you want to enable the sourceMap.

In order to do this, open the "**compilerconfig.json.defaults**" file that Web compiler automatically added to your project, and under sass, change the **sourceMap** to "**true**". This will turn on source mapping for all sass files. You can do this file by file basis as well (from compilerconfig.json) but i do not remember what exactly you needed to add there.